# Heroku not connecting to Heroku Postgres with CLI

Tags: postgresql, heroku

As mentioned in the title, I cannot connect to my Heroku Postgres database.

When I run the command to connect, this is the message that is returned.

```
heroku pg:psql postgresql-metric-xxxxx --app app-name
--> Connecting to postgresql-metric-xxxxx
 !    The local psql command could not be located. For help installing psql, see
 !    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup
```

However I have already installed PostgreSQL in my system running Windows 10.

Comment: Can you run the psql command locally?

Answer (score 3):

Remember to update your PATH environment variable to add the bin directory of your Postgres installation.
The directory will be similar to this:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<VERSION>\bin.
If you forget to update your PATH, commands like heroku pg:psql won’t work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to postgresql, you still need the postgresql client installed locally.

On a mac, you can install it with the `brew install postgresql` command.
On windows, you can find installation links [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).
On linux, it really depends on your distribution. But the `apt-get install postgresql` command is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `"pqsl`"  not in the PATH so run

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

at first time installation even if you add the 'path it will not load in the terminal if that is the case just restart the terminal by closing and reopening